# List of dictionaries similar to a Json string

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am reading a file that is of the form

```
[name, age]
```

So I am parsing each line in a loop and I want to save all the data for each line.
My idea was to use a list of dictionaries

```
var testData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

So as in the end to have something similar to this

```
{{Name: John; Age: 30},{Name: Doe; Age: 36}}
```

But I am not exactly sure how to do it. Trying to add a value to `testData` as such:

```
testData[0]["Name"] = "John";
```

Is not correct. How can I achieve this data structure in C#?

Comment: Did you initialize the dictionaries in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first assumption was good: you need to use `List<Dictionary<string, string>>();`.

However, you cannot simply assign values using indexers. You need to **Add** items to a dictionary.

Try the following code:

```
var testData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

testData.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Name", "John"},
    {"Age", "30"} // Note: Age is a string, and will result in "Age": "30"
});

testData.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Name", "Doe"},
    {"Age", "36"}
});

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData);
```

or you can use an object initializer:

```
var testData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Name", "John" },
        { "Age", "30" }
    },
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Name", "Doe" },
        { "Age", "36" }
    }
};

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData);
```

Another option is **to create a class, which represents your model**. For me it looks like a much better solution, if your file always represents the same model (Person):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; } // Note: Age is an int, and will result in "Age": 30

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

List<Person> testData = new List<Person>();
testData.Add(new Person("John", 30));
testData.Add(new Person("Doe", 36));

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData);
```

Comment: The third solution is of curse the best, yet all the suggestions are valid. Very informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend using Newtonsoft Json Serializer.
From my experience, it's easy to use.

Create a class with 2 properties (according your example): Name and Age.

```
class NamesAges
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then load from your file into list (dictionary seems redundant here).
Let's assume this is the list:

```
var namesAges = new List<NamesAges>
{
    new NamesAges {Name = "Abi", Age = 5},
    new NamesAges {Name = "Jhon", Age = 15},
    new NamesAges {Name = "Doe", Age = 20}
};
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(namesAges);
```

And you get:

```js
[{"Name":"Abi","Age":5},{"Name":"Jhon","Age":15},{"Name":"Doe","Age":20}]
```

You can find exactly what you want here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm